# Reading from binary file returns -1 without throwing EOFException

Tags: java, file, eofexception

I am trying to read one byte integers from a file. The integers are read correctly however the process keeps reading the integer '-1' without throwing an EOF exception.

This is how I write the integers into the file. I read 4 byte integers from class1.dat and put those which are below 256 in output1.dat as 1 byte integers.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\class1.dat");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\output1.dat");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

try
{
     while(true) 
     {
         number = dis.readInt();
         System.out.println("Integer read : " + number);

         if(number < 256)
             dos.write(number);

     }
}
catch(EOFException e)
{
      dis.close();
      dos.close();
}
```

This is how i read the 1 byte integers from output1.dat.

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\output1.dat"));


try
{
      int number;

      System.out.println("File with < 256");

      while(true)
      {
            number = dis.read();
            System.out.println("Number =  "  + number);
      }

}
catch(EOFException e)
{
      dis.close();
}
```

Why doesn't EOFexception get thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No EOFexception  is thrown because you use the read method from DataInputStream which is actually inherited from FilterInputStream.

And the doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read() says

> Returns:
>       the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.

No Exception is thrown when you reach the end of the stream.

You may want to use the method `readByte` instead which throws an EOFException when the input stream has reached the end.